# What are these odd files added to my Visual Studio MFC project?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, visual-studio-2005, projects-and-solutions, atl

I have a visual studio solution where one of the projects has somehow acquired several .bin files. They are named bin00001.bin, bin00002.bin, etc... and contains some kind of registry information. The contents of these files are one section repeated a number of times.

bin00001.bin:

```
HKCR
{
    NoRemove AppID
    {
        '%APPID%' = s 'ApplicationName'
                'ApplicationName.EXE'
                {
            val AppID = s '%APPID%'
        }
    }
}
HKCR
{
    NoRemove AppID
    {
        '%APPID%' = s 'ApplicationName'
                'ApplicationName.EXE'
                {
            val AppID = s '%APPID%'
        }
    }
}
```

This file had two copies of this section and the other files has. Note that a similar file applicat.bin seems to be the original file with one such section and I guess that it needs to be there.
What are these and why are there so many of them and why are they spread over so many files?

---

they are referenced in the .rc file and are designated resource identifiers in resource.h. I'm also pretty sure it generated a few of them when I added a couple of ATL classes. (I should maybe mention that this is an MFC project!) I'll add the tag

---

#### Update

I should maybe add that the executable contains a COM type library. Would this have anything to do with COM registration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out what they are.
Those .bin are replicas of the ApplicationName.rgs file.

I still don't know why Visual Studio created them in the first place though. Some kind of backup, I guess..?